# Update Kivy text variable with StringpPoperty and ID

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

So my problem is how do i update text to label. Should I use id:s in KV file and string property or is there even any other way?

Main.Py

````
    print_label = StringProperty()

    print_label = lyrics

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (.13, .13, .13, 1)
        return MyFloatLayout()```
my.kv
```<Button>:
    font_size: 40
    color: 0.1,0.5,0.6,1
    size_hint: 0.3, 0.1



<FloatLayout>:
    print_label: print_label

    Label:
        pos_hint:{"top":1}
        id: print_label
        text: ""


    Button:
        pos_hint:{"bottom":1}
        text: "RE-SEARCH"
        font_size: 10
        on_press: root.btn()
````

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide if you want `print_label` to be a `StringProperty` or an `ObjectProperty`. You are currently using `ObjectProperty` in kv and `StringProperty` in python.
If you want to use `StringProperty` you can set it directly to the text attribute. `text = root.print_label`. 
If you use it as `ObjectProperty` you bind it to the object. And you can access the objects properties like text, `print_label.text = "something"`. 
So you need to choose what you want `print_label` to be.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem - update Label's text

> how do i update text to label. Should I use id:s in KV file and string
>   property or is there even any other way?

### Solution

There are three options to the problem.

#### Option 1 - Using [ids](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#referencing-widgets)

The pros of using `ids` is that the App is smaller i.e. less coding and attributes used.

> An id is a weakref to the widget and not the widget itself. As a
>   consequence, storing the id is not sufficient to keep the widget from
>   being garbage collected.
>
> ...
>
> `self.ids` method is very concise.

**Snippets - py file**

```
class FloatLayout(FloatLayout):
    ...
    self.ids.print_label.text = lyrics
```

**Snippets - kv file**

```
<FloatLayout>:

    Label:
        pos_hint:{"top":1}
        id: print_label
        text: ""
```

#### Option 2 - Using [Stringproperty](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.StringProperty)

An attribute of type [Stringproperty](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.StringProperty) produce an event such that when the attribute's value changes, all properties that reference that attribute are automatically updated.

**Snippets - py file**

```
class FloatLayout(FloatLayout):
    print_label = StringProperty('')
    ...
    self.print_label = lyrics
```

**Snippets - kv file**

```
<FloatLayout>:

    Label:
        pos_hint:{"top":1}
        text: root.print_label
```

#### Option 3 - Using [Objectproperty](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.ObjectProperty)

Using [Objectproperty](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.ObjectProperty) to linking up a `Label` widget, also requires an `id` declared in kv file.

> Although the `self.ids` method is very concise, it is generally
>   regarded as ‘best practice’ to use the ObjectProperty. This creates a
>   direct reference, provides faster access and is more explicit.

**Snippets - py file**

```
class FloatLayout(FloatLayout):
    print_label = ObjectProperty(None)
    ...
    self.print_label.text = lyrics
```

**Snippets - kv file**

```
<FloatLayout>:
    print_label: print_label

    Label:
        pos_hint:{"top":1}
        id: print_label
        text: ""
```